# Taking a Textfield input converting to an int and then limiting the value

Tags: java

So im trying to take a Textfield input parsing to an int and then having on pressing enter. If the value is between say 1 and 50 you get an error if not it goes to the rest of my program. Im currently just testing to see if i can get the Action event to work.

This is what I have currently.

I get bad operand <= and >. I am not looking for anyone to just solve this but if anyone has any links or suggestions on what I am doing wrong that would be most appreciated.

public void init()
 {

```
setLayout( new FlowLayout());
label1= new JLabel( "Please enter number of rows" );
tf1= new JTextField(5);
String text = tf1.getText();
int first=Integer.parseInt(text);

add (label1);
add (tf1);

  tf1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //System.out.println("Enter pressed");

        if (e.getSource()<=20){
            System.out.println("Correct");
        }
        else if (e.getSource()>20){
            System.out.println("Try again");
        }
    }
}); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You expect `e.getSource()` to be the number entered, but what you get is the `TextField` which caused the event to happen. You can't compare a `TextField` to a number using `<` or such.

Since you register the `ActionListener` directly on the `TextField`, you don't have to check the source of the event. You know it will be the `TextField`.

What you want to do is :

In the case of an event (the `actionPerformed()` only gets called when an action happened in the TextField), if the key pressed was `Enter`, get the number from the `TextField` and check its value.

Comment: Thanks so much I have it now. I always hate the simple mistakes that just make you sit and scratch your head.